# iPhone : In-App Purchase(s) must be submitted with a new app version

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am trying to verify my in-app purchase.

For that I have uploaded my binary and added In-app purchase.

But at iTunes it is showing me like following

> Note:
>
> Your first In-App Purchase(s) must be submitted with a new app
>   version. Select them from the In-App Purchases section of the Version
>   Details page and then click Ready to Upload Binary.

But I did not find any option to make my in-app purchase `Ready to upload`.

What could be wrong ?

Comment: This solution is really helpful https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/35757#255475022

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I also made the same mistake and i Found it as per below steps

All other steps i think you have completed

- Login to iTunes connect
- Go to "Manage Your applications"
- Click on your application icon
- In that click on "View details"
- On that at bottom of your page you will find "In-App Purchase"
- Where you have to check mark your Non-consumable/Consumable/Auto-Renewable Product

and then submit

To cross check that
- Go to Manage In-App Purchase

where you will NOW find status "Ready to Upload"

Hope this help...

Comment: Must upload screenshot when you create IAP products otherwise the product is not ready and you'll not see In-App Purchase section in version details.

Answer (score 21):

If the state of your application is *Prepare For Upload* you can perform the following steps:
- Log In *ITunes Connect*
- Select *Manage Your Applications*
- Select your application (or search for it)
- Go to *View Details*
- Select *In App Purchases - Edit*
- Check your purchase
- Select Save

However, if you have already checked the application as "ready to submit" and this is in fact your first in-app purchase, you can't submit the in-app purchase directly. The following steps worked out for me:
- Submit the application once it is ready (I discourage submitting a half baked package)
- Log into *iTunes Connect*
- Select *Manage Your Applications*
- Select your application (or search for it)
- Select *View Details*
- Select *Binary Details* in the *Links* section
- Select *Reject Binary* and confirm
- Go to the *In App Purchases - Edit* section (should be available now)
- Check your purchase
- Select Save

*(Written according to the iTunes Connect Developer Guide 7.4)*

Comment: Best one. After Doing all, app IAP product will start showing `Waiting For Review`. and again submitting the app via xcode will do rest of the things.

Comment: In second option, "ready to submit", The Links section is not enabled, How can I reject it before submitting binary.

Answer (score 8):

#### Visual Version

Indeed, the In-App Purchases section appears after you get your In-App Purchase ready to be submitted and then upload a new build of your app. Here are some visuals to go along with this.

1. Get your first In-App Purchase ready for submission with all the details and screenshot, etc.
   [image: Get your In-App Purchase ready for submission.]
2. Upload a new version of your app (I change my version number but you might be able to just increment your build number).
3. Once that version is done processing, go to the iOS App section and scroll down. You should be able to see the In-App Purchases section now.
   [image: In-App Purchases Section]
4. Click the + icon and select any/all of your In-App Purchases.
   [image: Select Your In-App Purchases.]
5. Once added, you can now submit your app version, along with the selected In-App Purchases, for review. 
   [image: Submit for Review]

Answer (score 1):

Goto view details and proceed then click the "Ready to upload binary" then continue 
after go to Manage In-app purchase on your in-app detail the "Submit For Review" will be enabled. Here you can submit it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your in app purchase then create an test user in your itunes a/c and manage your in app purchase in your app by clicking on manage in app purchase button...

it takes some time...... after that by test user a/c u can test it in your app....

Comment: I have already create Test User but I did not find Ready to upload binary for In-app purchase. And I have also uploaded my project.

Comment: how can u upload your binary without clicking on ready to upload binary button in itunes.....its present in your itunes a/c where you create a new entry for your application for uploading.. after uploading all information you see both manage in app purchase button and ready to upload binary button....

Comment: Its for app. But it is also asking for ready to upload for `inapp` purchase. And I dont know How to do that ?

Comment: Ok...When you make your app entry at itunes then in app information one button for manage In app pur. present. by the help of this you can make an entry for in app item or add more items...

Comment: yes I have already added using that but after adding in-app purchase it is showing my in-app list in the table where the top of the screen i got the `above notes` as shown in question..

Answer (score 0):

In your current version edit "InApp purchase" section and select available in-apps. Than this warning will be dismissed. It works for me...