# in-app purchase show warning not available inapp in iTunes connect

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, app-store-connect

iTunes shows warning for in-app purchase creating **Your first In-App Purchase(s) must be submitted with a new app version. Select them from the In-App Purchases section of the Version Details page and then click Ready to Upload Binary.** like  below screenshot :

[image]

i am try lot of instruction fixing this issue but not work,i am create inapp scenario below instruction:

first i am create app in iTunes connect and status is **Ready to upload Binary**

after create manage-inapppurchase->add new->create in-app and shows status **Ready to Submit**

and shows the warning message **Your first In-App Purchase(s) must be submitted with a new app version. Select them from the In-App Purchases section of the Version Details page and then click Ready to Upload Binary.**

ok i am after upload binary and reject it and goes to inapp shows same warning message..!

i am try to lot of way but does not work can any one help me for fixing this issue in iTunes connect with greatly appreciated...!

Thanks....!

Comment: look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677857/iphone-in-app-purchases-must-be-submitted-with-a-new-app-version

Answer (score 1):

All other steps i think you have completed

Request **iOS Free Applications** Contracts.

1. Login to iTunes connect
2. Go to "Manage Your applications"
3. Click on your application icon
4. In that click on "View details"
5. On that at bottom of your page you will find "In-App Purchase"
6. Where you have to check mark your
   Non-consumable/Consumable/Auto-Renewable Product

and then **Ready To Upload Binary**

To cross check that - Go to Manage In-App Purchase

where you will NOW find status "Ready to Upload"

Hope this help...

Comment: I've uploaded demo app with paypal sandbox integration. They rejected my binary with response :"We noticed that your app enables the purchase of content, services, or functionality in the app by means other than the In-App Purchase API, which is not allowed on the App Store." I am using sandbox a/c of paypal. Is In-App-Purchase is mandatory?

Answer (score 0):

Try enter in View Details and click on link at "In-App Purchases"

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your iOS Paid Apps contract from Contracts, Tax, and Banking section of iTunes connect.