# In App Purchase link not find on iTunes connect on my application

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, app-store-connect

i am read this post [In-app Purchase "ready to submit", but won't let me submit it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088560/in-app-purchase-ready-to-submit-but-wont-let-me-submit-it) i will see one answer below :

@Ran :I was having the same problem. It would not let me submit my In app purchases to my app, which I uploaded shortly beforehand. I had to reject the binary, then follow the directions below to add the IAP to the app version before uploading.

Go to iTunes Connect

- Click on Manage your applications
- Click on the App
- Click "View Details" button
- Scroll down until you see an "In App Purchase" Section
- Add your In App Purchase to that version.
- Then ready your app for upload.
- Once these steps are complete, the In App Purchase should automatically change from "Ready to Submit" to "Waiting for Review".

in this i am following steps but i am stuck on step: **Scroll down until you see an "In App Purchase" Section**

i am not find my application link can't find **InAppPurchase** link

i am see find links below screen shot:

[image]

how to find **InAppPurchase** link on my app on iTunes connect..!

Please Help with me greatly appreciated..!

THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

You can see the InAppPurchase Link in Manage Application -> open your application there you will find some links like pricing and some as shown in figure.
This will work if and only if you enable InAppPurchase in your application bundle id in developer.apple.com
[image]

if you press View details
[image]

like this button this will take to description page there you will not find InAppPurchase

you can find only these option so check in before page ie. Manage Application - > go to your application

[image]

Comment: ok next step Add your In App Purchase to that version. how to do it?

Comment: You have go to Manage In-App Purchases and there at top left side "Create New" button will be there, there you can add new InAppPurchase with new ReferenceName and New product Id like "com.companyName.AppName_proUpGradeV2"

Comment: :i am already create inapppurchase but,it shows warning message "Your first In-App Purchase(s) must be submitted with a new app version. Select them from the In-App Purchases section of the Version Details page and then click Ready to Upload Binary."

Comment: read my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045092/in-app-purchase-show-warning-not-available-inapp-in-itunes-connect

Comment: I think you have created two InAppPurchase for the same application.
First delete the inapppurchase In Manage InAppPurchase. Check this Video Tutorial https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=510 and try again it will definitely work