# Itunes Connect In App Purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

While configuring the In App Purchase in ItunesConnect I get the following warning
"Your first In-App Purchase(s) must be submitted with a new app version. Select them from the In-App Purchases section of the Version Details page and then click Ready to Upload Binary." ,I googled about this for a solution and found alink "[iPhone : In-App Purchase(s) must be submitted with a new app version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677857/iphone-in-app-purchases-must-be-submitted-with-a-new-app-version)" and edited in the view details InApp Purchase section even though the warning doesn't go off...I am pretty stuck with this can anyone suggest me a good answer for this..Thanks in advance

Comment: did you add screen shots when creating the in-app products?

Comment: ya finished every process and i saved.

Comment: what is the status of the app in the app summary page?

Comment: sorry the status in the app summary page is "Prepare for Upload"

Answer (score 1):

Tap the View Details Button on the app summary page and add your in-app purchases to review from the In-App Purchases section in the app summary page, (In the reference image it doesn't give the option to add in-app purchases since it's already in the app store.)

[image]

Comment: ya i checked a tick on my In app Purchase product there Ushan still its showing the same warning

Comment: where do you see that warning?

Comment: Inside the Manage In app Purchase and when clicking on the reference name of my In app Purchase product I get this warning

Comment: "Note:
Your first In-App Purchase(s) must be submitted with a new app version. Select them from the In-App Purchases section of the Version Details page and then click Ready to Upload Binary." You mean this rite? it's not a warning. it's a note to yourself :) just tick your products from the app summary page and press "Ready to upload Binary" button.

Comment: Do we have to upload binary for testing the InApp Purchase(sand boxing)

Comment: You mean to send the application for testers?

Comment: I need to test the weather the Purchasing going fine First in sandboxing enviroment For that i have created test users in itunesConnect in ManageUsers section

Comment: ok then first go to settings app in your iPhone and sign out from the existing app store account. and then go and purchase the account from your app. It will give you an alert to sign in from a existing account. Give the login details of the test user and test whether the in-app is working

Comment: Ushan I am following MKStoreKit tutorial "http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/using-mkstorekit-in-your-apps/" and created a simple Button action for doing In app Purchase ,Now the error what I am getting is "Problem in iTunes connect configuration for product:"

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with MKStoreKit. Does the error comes up when you try to purchase the product or when trying to show your products list?

Comment: Sorry mate I can't help you with this anymore because I'm not familiar with MKStoreKit. Why do you use MKStoreKit in the first place? why can't you just use the methods provided by Apple to do in-app purchases. seriously it won't take much time just go through this tutorial and get a clear idea about how to add an in-app purchase

http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial

and then follow this tutorial to add consumable products as in-app :)

http://www.raywenderlich.com/23266/in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial-consumables-and-receipt-validation

Comment: ya k I will look at this and thank you soo much for spending your time helping me out in this problem thanks once again..

Comment: thanks once again Ushan I found a good solution from your In app Purchase link...

Answer (score 0):

The mistake what I have made was I have entered the product Id in iTuneConnect apple in Invalid format ,The format should be "com.yourcompnyname.Appname.ProductId"

Answer (score 0):

Please find below details how to add IAP in your application.

1. Create product from manage inapp purchase from application.
2. Now when you go into view detail button below project icon, you need to send IAP in review process also. if you have submitted application binary without submitted IAP, then your application will be rejected.
3. In that case you can reject binary and go to application detail. Go below to send IAP in review. after submitted it, you can click on "Ready to upload binary". if you will click on it without sending IAP in review, it will give you same error as giving.

So, if you have submitted your application without IAP, better you will reject it and upload it again. Otherwise APPLE will definitely reject it and it will waste of your time.

Comment: My problem is precisely that Apple didn't reject a binary with a missing in-app purchase, it doesn't work in the published app, and now the section in the above screenshot has completely disappeared for me :(