# App Rejected - In App Purchase - Developer action needed

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

My app got rejected because of In-App Purchase issues and the status of all of my In-App Purchase products is changed to Rejected.

I googled the issue and did a little fake change in the Description of the In-App Products just to change the Status to "Waiting For Review".

Now my question is Do I have to Wait for Apple Review team to review my In-App purchase and change the Status to "Ready to Submit"?

or

I can just Submit my Build again with In-App Purchase status "Waiting For Review"

Also I read somewhere there I have to Select the In-App Purchase in my App Detail Page before submitting the Binary for Review. But I can't Find any thing like " In-App Purchase " in My App Details Page.

Can you please, provide me step by step instruction on how can I resubmit my App with Proper In-App Purchase.

Comment: I believe that you can just re-submit your app once you have addressed the in-app issues.

Comment: You better check why your IAP items are rejected. First time IAP will be approved together with the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this link-

[iPhone : In-App Purchase(s) must be submitted with a new app version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677857/iphone-in-app-purchases-must-be-submitted-with-a-new-app-version)

Before app submission you have to submit your all products.

Comment: When I click on my application Icon, it directs me to the versions tab, in that tab there should be a section to Select In-App purchase below the Build Section. But I can't find that InApp Section in that page.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a new binary to itunesconnect and wait for Apple review. This is all you need to do. They will review your in app purchases also.

Answer (score 0):

Like @RaviGautam already wrote, the creation of an `In-App-Purchase` must be submitted and also connected to the app inside the panel you also can change the description and selecting the build. [In this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingInAppPurchases.html) its first described where to add an In-App-Purchase in `iTunesConnect` to the app you want to use it inside.

This must be done before submitting the app. If you defined In-App-Purchases but didn't connect them to your app, apple will reject you app because you must have any if you setup your app with In-App-Purchase when creating the App-ID.

Also changing an In-App-Purchase description or anything else, it must be submitted and reviewed by the apple team before user can use it inside the app.

Here its described how to connect the IAP with your app on the app details page:

[image]

Comment: So, basically I have to wait for the Apple Review team to review my InApp purchase and change it's status from "Waiting for Review" to Ready or something , and then only I can Submit the App.

Comment: I think submitting the app and changed In-App-Purchases will be possible at the same time. They will be reviewing both or I think they review the In-App-Purchases a little bit faster than a whole app. But you shouldn't forget to connect your In-App-Purchases to the app inside iTunesConnect in the Apps detail page ( check my link --> To submit the first In-App Purchase product for an app) .

Comment: I checked your Link, and I can't find any thing like that, there is no InApp section in my version tab below the Build Section.

Comment: Added a screenshot with the description from the page I posted already.

Comment: http://s18.postimg.org/7hm00ikyh/Screen_Shot_2015_03_03_at_3_30_25_PM.png    Here is the ScreenShot of my ItunesConnect App Details, there is no section for In-App Purchase :(

Comment: I think this section will appear after apple approve my all In-App purchase

Comment: Normally this appears if you create the app in iTunesConnect and did already add any IAP in the IAP-section. But I'm sure its also available when they rejected it.

Comment: Actually I am updating a Live app by adding few more In-App purchase, does this change the process

Comment: Normally it shouldn't, But you will have to review your app again I think, because you also have to connect the app to the new InAppPurchases when creating a new version of your app. Just tell me if you could solve this problem, In-App-Purchase is never fun!

Comment: I just Re-submitted my app and it's accepted. So, this means, In-App purchase section only appears for the first time in the App Version details.

Comment: Not only the first time I think, It should always appear after adding a new In App Purchase. You always have to connect the IAP and the app.